# OAuth Implementation: Issues with client_id causing authentication failures

Tags: laravel, react-native, oauth, expo

I'm currently implementing OAuth in my React Native app using Expo, and I've encountered an issue with the client_id parameter that is causing authentication failures. I've followed the standard OAuth flow, but when I exchange the authorization code for an access token, the server returns an error indicating that the client_id is invalid.

Problem:

The client_id is generated when registering the app with the OAuth provider.
I've verified that the client_id in my code matches the one registered with the provider.
Other OAuth parameters seem to be correctly configured, and the flow works up until the point of exchanging the authorization code.

```
// ... code related to generating authorization URL and handling callback

const fetchAccessToken = async (query) => {
  try {
    // ... code to construct request URL

    let result = await WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync(completeURL);

    // ... code to handle response
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching access token:", error);
  }
};
```

1.Could there be any common reasons for the client_id mismatch during the OAuth token exchange process?
2. Is there any specific formatting or encoding required for the client_id when making the request?
3. Are there any debugging techniques I can use to investigate this further and ensure that the client_id is being sent correctly?
4. Are there any best practices or steps I might be missing in handling the client_id parameter during the OAuth flow in a React Native Expo app?

I'd greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions to help troubleshoot and resolve this issue. If additional code or information is needed, please let me know.